# Remove repeated rows with inverted values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)


col_1     col_2     
 A           B        
 B           A 
 A           C
```

I would like to remove the duplicated rows, with inverted values, obtaining:

```
print(df_final)


col_1     col_2     
 A           B        
 A           C
```

I tried with `.drop_duplicates(subset = ["col_1", "col_2])` but it doesn't produce the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sort along column and drop duplicates to do that

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'B'], ['B', 'D']], columns=('col_1', 'col_2'))

result = df.loc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).drop_duplicates().index]
```

**Result**

```
col_1 col_2
0     A     B
1     B     A
2     A     C
3     C     B
4     B     D


 col_1 col_2
0     A     B
2     A     C
3     C     B
4     B     D
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `duplicated`:

```
df[df.duplicated(['col_1'], keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2
0     A     B
2     A     C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(data={"col_1": ["A", "B", "A"], "col_2": ["B", "A", "C"]})

df["col_3"]=df.apply(lambda x: str(sorted(x.values)), axis=1)

df=df.drop_duplicates("col_3").drop("col_3", axis=1)

print(df)
```

And output:

```py
   col_1 col_2
0     A     B                                               
2     A     C                                               
[Program finished]
```